# What is the use of static synchronized method in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one question in my mind. I have read that static synchronized method locks in the class object
and synchronized method locks the current instance of an object. So what's the meaning of *locked*
on class object?

Can anyone please help me on this topic?

Comment: Any "synchronized" method or block is "locked" on entry such that only one thread at a time can execute that method/block (relative to the lock object).  Additionally, only one thread at a time can execute *any* method/block locked on the same object.  A static synchronized method is locked on the Class object.

Comment: @Zavior I don't think it's a duplicate - the question you linked is about "how it is done", while this question is about "why it is done".

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think you are right

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In general, `synchronized` methods are used to protect access to resources that are accessed concurrently. When a resource that is being accessed concurrently belongs to each instance of your class, you use a `synchronized` instance method; when the resource belongs to all instances (i.e. when it is in a `static` variable) then you use a `synchronized static` method to access it.

For example, you could make a `static` factory method that keeps a "registry" of all objects that it has produced. A natural place for such registry would be a `static` collection. If your factory is used from multiple threads, you need to make the factory method `synchronized` (or have a `synchronized` block inside the method) to protect access to the shared `static` collection.

Note that using `synchronized` without a specific lock object is generally not the safest choice when you are building a library to be used in code written by others. This is because malicious code could synchronize on your object or a class to block your own methods from executing. To protect your code against this, create a private "lock" object, instance or static, and synchronize on that object instead.

Answer (score 95):

At run time every loaded class has an instance of a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object. That is the object that is used as the shared lock object by `static synchronized` methods. (Any synchronized method or block has to lock on *some* shared object.)

You can also synchronize on this object manually if wanted (whether in a static method or not). These three methods behave the same, allowing only one thread at a time into the inner block:

```
class Foo {
    static synchronized void methodA() {
        // ...
    }

    static void methodB() {
        synchronized (Foo.class) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    static void methodC() {
        Object lock = Foo.class;
        synchronized (lock) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The intended purpose of `static synchronized` methods is when you want to allow only one thread at a time to use some mutable state stored in `static` variables of a class.

Nowadays, Java has more powerful concurrency features, in [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and its subpackages, but the core Java 1.0 constructs such as `synchronized` methods are still valid and usable.

Comment: Hats off... This topic was not clear util I read your answer. Even java doc didn't give sight like you did.....

Comment: what about just `synchronized { ... }` block inside a `static` method (i.e. without explicitly specifying the lock object for the synchronized block)? is it also equivalent, and assumes that the lock object to use is the class itself?

Comment: @AdamBurley There is no such syntax. It will not compile.

Answer (score 73):

In simple words a `static synchronized` method will lock the class instead of the object, and it will lock the class because the keyword `static` means: "class instead of instance".

The keyword `synchronized` means that only one thread can access the method at a time.
And `static synchronized` mean:

> Only one thread can access the class at one time.

Comment: Also see for more details - http://www.javatpoint.com/static-synchronization-example

Comment: best one in just 4 lines :)

Answer (score 13):

Suppose there are multiple static synchronized methods (m1, m2, m3, m4) in a class, and suppose one thread is accessing m1, then no other thread at the same time can access any other static synchronized methods.

Comment: How about static variables?

Answer (score 1):

static methods can be synchronized. But you have one lock per class. when the java class is loaded coresponding java.lang.class class object is there. That object's lock is needed for.static synchronized methods.
 So when you have a static field which should be restricted to be accessed by multiple threads at once you can set those fields private and create public static synchronized setters or getters to access those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Java VM contains a single class object per class. Each class may have some shared variables called static variables. If the critical section of the code plays with these variables in a concurrent environment, then we need to make that particular section as synchronized. When there is more than one static synchronized method only one of them will be executed at a time without preemption. That's what lock on class object does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've already got your answer from above but I'll explain the question to ensure my knowledge.

I believe here is an instance of *synchronized method locks currents instance of an object.*

```
//Your object

class Y {

//Method

 void method(){

//No need synchronized lines of code

  synchronized (this) {

/* The lines of code *instance of an object* runing concurrently 
without the outer block of code */

/* Synchronized method will execute only one current at a time if
it (the instance of the object) is concurrent and lock every other current */

  }

//No need synchronized lines of code

 }
}
```

So, in my opinion, the meaning of locking in class object in *Static Synchronized Method* is exactly the same as *Synchronized Method*
but in larger scale (Class Object)!

Comment: This post has been placed in the answer section, but it sounds like it might be a question. Could you confirm whether this is an answer?